# Ugly roots using newtxmath: alternatives

Tags: math-mode, packages, newtxmath, newtx, mathastext

In this period I am writing several notes of Mathematical Analysis and Physics for my students during this bad period for the pandemic, also attaching videolessons for *distance learning* or *distance education*. I have noticed that using the cubic root or index `n` packets, they are very close together and ugly.

Which different packages (included in the `MikTeX` distribution) or some alternative you recommend to associate, in math-mode with the clone of Times New Roman: `newtxtext`.....and `newtxmath`? I thinked to `mathastext` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt[3]{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick with the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages, I would use the `\uproot` and `\leftroot` macros -- provided originally by the `amsmath` package but included in `newtxmath` as well -- to fine-tune the position of the nth-root symbol.

There is no single "optimal" value for the arguments of `\uproot` and `\leftroot`, as a "good" positioning will depend on the value of the nth root. The following screenshot and code considers the cases `3` and `n`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt[3]{2} \quad \sqrt[\uproot{2}3]{2} \quad \sqrt[\leftroot{1}\uproot{2}3]{2}$

$\sqrt[n]{2} \quad \sqrt[\uproot{3}n]{2} \quad \sqrt[\leftroot{1}\uproot{3}n]{2}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much to you and also a Vincent. But my problem it is remember the `\uproot` macro :-(

Answer (score 2):

You could keep working with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`, but modify the `\sqrt` command to move a little the degree of the root.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\let\oldsqrt\sqrt
\renewcommand{\sqrt}[2][]{%
    \oldsqrt[\raisebox{1pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Regular root:               & \( \oldsqrt[3]{2}, \oldsqrt[k]{2}, \oldsqrt[n]{2} \) \\
    With \verb|\raisebox{1pt}|: & \(    \sqrt[3]{2},    \sqrt[k]{2},    \sqrt[n]{2} \)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think it already looks better, especially for the *k*-th and *n*-th roots.

Comment: no need for raisebox, amsmath and newtxmath  provide specific commands to move the index

Comment: Yes, I learned that from Mico's answer. It's good to know!

Comment: Thank you very much also to you.